# Road Intersection Mapping Using Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a project to model traffic roads using matrix; currently I'm trying to use `numpy.matrix` to do so.

Problem statement: Suppose we would like to go from location `i` to `j`. The matrix element `M_ij` tells us the distance to walk from `i` to `j`. Now, things are easy if we only intend to move once.
But I want python to be able to explore all possibilities of all possible roads that can be traversed. The main problem here is that I am trying to find **the shortest route between any two points**.

That is to say, supposing that we want to go from `i=1 to j=4`, I want to compare the results of:

M_12+M_23+M_34 with

M_13+M_34 with

M_12+M_24 with etc. (You get the idea)

e.g. The following describes the "paths"/"roads" from 1 location to another location. That is, the distance from location 1 to location 3 is denoted by the matrix element M_13, which is the element in Row 1 and column 3 i.e. 9 metres (because Python counts from zero for index of matrix).

```
  1, 3, 5, 4
  4, 5, 3, 9
  3, 6, 6, 4
  9, 8, 9, 7
```

So let's say I want to go from location 2 to location 0. That means that there are the following possible paths that I can take:

M_20 = 3 metres

M_21 + M_10 = Go from location 2 to location 1, and then location 1 to location 0 =6+4=10 metres

etc....

That is to say, I want to compare ALL these possible paths, and then I want to see which path is the shortest.

I have tried using the numpy's method:

```
import numpy
numpy.my_matrix.sum
```

But it returns me the summation of ALL the elements (i.e. M_11+M_12+M_13+M_14+M_21+M_22+...+M_44)

Does anyone know how to work around this "bug"?
Thank you so much!

Comment: can you provide a sample of the matrix and an expected output to help you solve this; ```numpy.matrix.sum()```will provide you the sum of all the elements in the matrix, so it is working as expected. Refer to this : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.sum.html

Comment: Yeah I know; that is why I used "bug" instead of bug. I know that it returns all the elements' summation. But what I expect is not that